# Prometheus HTTP API

Tags: prometheus

I'm using Prometheus HTTP API queries to get required API data to PowerBI. Refereed Prometheus doc link as follows :

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/

There I'm getting a JSON result as below. Can anyone help me on figuring out what is the highlighted value indicate ?  (value 1435781451.781)

```
          "value": [ **1435781451.781**, "1" ]
```

Seems it is an UNIX timestamp. But what is that timestamp? It is changing every time when we execute the query.

I want to get the actual API call timestamp.

```html
$ curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=up&time=2015-07-01T20:10:51.781Z'
{
   "status" : "success",
   "data" : {
      "resultType" : "vector",
      "result" : [
         {
            "metric" : {
               "__name__" : "up",
               "job" : "prometheus",
               "instance" : "localhost:9090"
            },
            "value": [ 1435781451.781, "1" ]
         },
         {
            "metric" : {
               "__name__" : "up",
               "job" : "node",
               "instance" : "localhost:9100"
            },
            "value" : [ 1435781451.781, "0" ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Your question is curious. The value is a UNIX timestamp. If you plug it into a tool like [EpochConvertor](https://www.epochconverter.com/) you can see that `1435781451.781` is `2015-07-01T20:10:51.781Z` in RFC-3339. Since the query specifies this timestamp, the `value`'s returned must match the timestamp and so it should not be possible for the `value` to not match `time=`. You do not demonstrate this fact in your question. In your question, the `value`'s match the `time` value.

Comment: @DazWilkin what is that timestamp indicates ? Query executing time?

Comment: The timestamp of the measurement .... i.e. 1435781451.781 was when the server scraped the `up` metric on `prometheus` (`localhost:9090`) and `node` (`localhost:9100`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a Unix timestamp in seconds, see https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-vectors.

The timestamp of each sample in an instant-vector-typed result of an instant query will always be equal to the query's evaluation timestamp. The evaluation timestamp is either explicitly provided via the `time=...` HTTP parameter, or when omitted, the Prometheus server chooses its own current server time as the evaluation timestamp (see https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/76b0d26be84b4f653e42c620a78850ad17b580c9/web/api/v1/api.go#L383). Maybe the latter is what you are looking for?

These two blog posts could also be interesting for getting a better understanding how a PromQL query is executed overall, and how selectors within a query work:

- https://promlabs.com/blog/2020/06/18/the-anatomy-of-a-promql-query
- https://promlabs.com/blog/2020/07/02/selecting-data-in-promql

Comment: My requirements is not to get the query's evaluation time. I need to get the traffic of each API groups against to a specific time to create a dashboard, there I want to make a graph against API call time. In that case do you know any possible scenario / PromQL to get the API call time rather than server scraped time.

Comment: Do you care about individual requests to the monitored server's API and their timestamp? In that case, you will need an event tracking system and not Prometheus, which only stores and handles periodically sampled numeric metrics.

Comment: No , not an individual monitoring I am focusing on getting per minute or hourly summarise counts. therefore I need API data against its actual timestamps. Will that possible ?